# Segmentation fault 11

Tags: c, command-line, segmentation-fault

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#define MAXLINE 512
main(int argc,char* argv[]){
    FILE *fi;
    fi=open(argv[1],"r");
    char linie[MAXLINE],*p;
    for ( ; ; ) {
        p = fgets(linie, MAXLINE, fi);
        linie[MAXLINE-1] = '\0';
        printf("%s", linie);
    }
    fclose(fi);

};
```

Hello,
I have this code, basically what I am trying to do is create an c source for printing a file given in the command line parameters , could somebody please tell me why I get a segmentation 11 fault ?
Thanks

Comment: Can you check *where* you get a segmentation fault? This can be done by for example looking at the trace from `valgrind ./yourprogram`

Comment: Well that loop looks a little suspect.

Comment: Maybe your `fi=open(argv[1],"r");` resulted iin a NULL file pointer? @austin: yes the loop is suspect, but it will only loop, not crash.

Comment: OK, I checked - it's on the line `p = fgets(linie, MAXLINE, fi);` that you have an `invalid read of size 4`. Don't know why, though...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

1. Your `for` loop doesn't end.
2. You don't check the result from `fgets`, which gives `NULL` when you reach the end of the file. Nor do you check the result of `fopen`, which gives `NULL` when the file cannot be opened.
3. You don't check whether `argc` is at least 2 before using `argv[1]`
4. You're using `open` instead of `fopen`

Hint: use `-Wall -pedantic` if you're using GCC.

Answer (score 3):

You are calling `open()` where you probably meant to call `fopen()`. You shouldn't ignore compiler warnings.

Also, you should check the return value of `fopen()` to make sure it isn't `NULL`.

Comment: You didn't get a "makes pointer from integer without a cast" warning?

Answer (score 1):

A fixed version:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#define MAXLINE 512
main(int argc,char* argv[]){
    FILE *fi;
    if (argc < 2)
        return;
    fi=fopen(argv[1], "r");
    if (!fi)
        return;
    char linie[MAXLINE],*p;
    for ( ; ; ) {
        p = fgets(linie, MAXLINE, fi);
        if (p == NULL)
            break;
        linie[MAXLINE-1] = '\0';
        printf("%s", linie);
    }
    fclose(fi);
};
```